# How do I fix create-react-app not loading CSS Modules?

Tags: reactjs

I created a new react app by Create-React-App and I tried to use CSS Modules, but it's doesn't seem to work anymore.
here is my simple usage of CSS modules :

```
import styles from './myStyle.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's work on my older project, the only differences in my older project with the new one is the react-scripts version.

my new project dependencies :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  }
```

my old project dependencies :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
```

Has anything changed in react-scripts v3 ?

Comment: Can you elaborate the "not working" concept? Are you getting an error? The app works but you don't see any style?

Comment: There's no error, but the values aren't resolved. Instead, the variable name remains in the actual CSS. Since it's of course an invalid value, the styles are just ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use CSS module, you should name your file to `[name].module.css`:

> This project supports CSS Modules alongside regular stylesheets using the `[name].module.css` file naming convention. CSS Modules allows the scoping of CSS by automatically creating a unique classname of the format `[filename]\_[classname]\_\_[hash]`.

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

Comment: The fact this is necessary is a regression bug in CRA 3.0.0. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7306

Comment: and normally it must be done using import styles from 'fileName.module.css' and then use the styles object to call sub classes names : className={{styles.className}}